# How to I upgrade my Galaxy Fit from 2.2 to 2.3 using Ubuntu?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.3-gingerbread, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade firmware on my Samsung Galaxy S without using windows?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-do-i-upgrade-firmware-on-my-samsung-galaxy-s-without-using-windows)
>   [How do I update the OS on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-on-my-device)

I have a Samsung Galaxy Fit (GT-S5670) running Android 2.2.1. I'm trying to upgrade it to 2.3 on an Ubuntu machine.

I tried to run Samsung Kies using Wine, and below is the output I got:

```
fixme:advapi:LookupAccountNameW (null) L"thillaiselvan" (nil) 0x32c264 (nil) 0x32c268 0x32c25c - stub
fixme:advapi:LookupAccountNameW (null) L"thillaiselvan" 0x1449b8 0x32c264 0x14d270 0x32c268 0x32c25c - stub
fixme:advapi:LookupAccountNameW (null) L"thillaiselvan" (nil) 0x32c264 (nil) 0x32c268 0x32c25c - stub
fixme:advapi:LookupAccountNameW (null) L"thillaiselvan" 0x152638 0x32c264 0x150b18 0x32c268 0x32c25c - stub
```

Then Kies stopped. What is the problem here?

Comment: I would recommend running Kies on a Windows machine, it's buggy enough as is, running it on Wine is going to be VERY painful.

Answer (score 3):

The process is explained pretty well on Samsung's official page, found [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/SWUP/JSP). Just download Kies, install it, plug in your phone, wait for it to be recognized and upgrade.

Comment: hi once downloaded the kies, will it be automatically get installed or any manual works are there

Comment: Just run the installer, it will install Kies and should install the drivers too. Then run Kies and plug your phone in, it should be recognized automatically.